# Weird <div> overlay on chrome

Tags: html, css

I have a text input that thinks there is another div element floating over it. When you hover the mouse over, the cursor stays the same. Only a few small parts of the text input can be clicked on.

When you inspect element it shows that it "thinks" you were hovering over the `header-resize` .

See it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/HxHDK/2/ (Sorry I know a lot of resources are missing, but the problem is still there)

The text input that is bugged is the To: field. This is only happening on google chrome.

I tried adding z-index attributes but did not work.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

weird behavior, but can be fixed by adding `overflow: hidden;` to `.header` rule declaration

Answer (score 1):

Removing the negative top margin on `.content` solves this indeed weird issue.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `height` attribute from `header` and the problem is gone.

Comment: Both you and Philipe have great answers, +1 to both of you. But unfortunately they both have some unwanted side effects on my site while Ejay's answer keeps everything else the same.